# Using falcor to retrieve the value of a "node" rather than a "leaf"

Tags: falcor

For example, with the following code, I can retrieve a value for "leaf" `c` from a Falcor model

```
var model = new falcor.Model({ cache: { a: { b: { c: 'hi!'}}} })
model.getValue('a.b.c').then(val => console.log(val));
```

However, I'm interested in how to retrieve "node" `b`, i.e. so that the resulting json is `{ c: 'hi!' }`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this is by storing "c"as a jsongraph atom into b.